# MS Access VBA: dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Inside of a function, I am using a string to run sql.  I need to vary some of the string dependent on user selection. For brevity, I have included only one field from each table.  Also, these are not the real table names.

```
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblWax"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblWax ( strPortName, lngShortSet ) " & _
         "SELECT tblAAA.strPastName, tblBBB.lngShortID " & _
         "FROM tblAAA INNER JOIN tblBBB ON tblAAA.Parameter = tblBBB.Parameter"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

I would like to substitute tblSSS for tblBBB depending on user choice and with that same choice (within the field strChoice), tblWax needs to be tblHat.  That is:
if strChoice = 1, then tblWax, tblAAA, tblBBB
if strChoice = 2, then tblHat, tblAAA, tblSSS

Otherwise, the rest of the string(s) is identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Smandoli's and @Gustav's answer on using string variables for the table names.  This allows you to create multiple cases without the variable names getting lost in the SQL string.

```
Select Case strChoice

    Case 1:
        strTarget = "tblWax"
        strJoin = "tblBBB"

    Case 2:
        strTarget = "tblHat"
        strJoin = "tblSSS"

end select

strSQL = "DELETE * FROM " & strTarget
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strTarget & " ( strPortName, lngShortSet ) " & _
         "SELECT tblAAA.strPastName, " & strJoin & ".lngShortID " & _
         "FROM tblAAA INNER JOIN " & strJoin & _
         " ON tblAAA.Parameter = " & strJoin & ".Parameter"

db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use conditional logic like VBA's `SELECT...CASE`

```
Select Case strChoice

   Case 1
      strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblWax"
      db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

      strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblWax ( strPortName, lngShortSet ) " & _
               "SELECT tblAAA.strPastName, tblBBB.lngShortID " & _
               "FROM tblAAA INNER JOIN tblBBB ON tblAAA.Parameter = tblBBB.Parameter"

   Case 2
      strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblHat"
      db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

      strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblHat ( strPortName, lngShortSet ) " & _
               "SELECT tblAAA.strPastName, tblSSS.lngShortID " & _
               "FROM tblAAA INNER JOIN tblSSS ON tblAAA.Parameter = tblSSS.Parameter"

End Select

db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

You can even use multiple values in one case

```
Case 1, 3, 5
...
Case 2, 4, 6
...
```

And use an `Else` for the rest that do not follow other `Case` statements

```
Case Else
...
```

Comment: This can be refactored by using string variables in the SQL, for example `strTargetTable = "tblWax"`.

Comment: Indeed. The SQL doesn't change, so use the _select-case_ to determine the tablenames, then substitute placeholders in the SQL with the tablenames.

Comment: I do like the select case by itself but while the number of cases is small now it may not be in the future. So, I will use the select case to change a variable to the table name and put that variable in the SQL.  Thanks to all.

Comment: Having to change the structural components like table names brings into question your database design. Think about normalization (related tables in logical groupings) and not many similar structured tables. Such a design scales and stores more efficiently and queries are much easier (no need for many conditionals). For instance, couldn't *tblWax* and *tblHat* be incorporated into same table with indicator field for *wax* and *hat* values.